# Выборка строк по разнице дат

Tags: php, mysql

Каким образом можно выбрать строки из таблицы, в которых разница между текущей датой и датой в поле `date` равна 10 дням?

Формат даты в таблице YYYY-MM-DD.

```
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table WHERE ...");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так:

```
select email from table where datediff(now(), date) = 10;
```

если *mysql* не сможет «разобраться» с форматом данных в столбце `date`, может потребоваться явное преобразование с помощью, например, `str_to_date`:

```
str_to_date(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

подробности смотрите в документации по упомянутым функциям.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал php, запрос должен быстрей выполнятся (да и разобраться потом проще будет):

```
$dateFrom = date('Y-m-d');
$dateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 day'));
$query = "SELECT email FROM table WHERE date > '$dateFrom' && date < '$dateTo'";
```